# .Net 5's HashSet<string> + SequenceEqual() result surprising?

Tags: .net, .net-5

Given code like this...

```
var a = new HashSet<string>(){  "A", "A", "B" };
var b = new HashSet<string>(){  "A", "B" };

var areTheyEqual = a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

I'd expect areTheyEqual to be **false**, however it is ***true***:
[image]

Looking at the [documentation for .SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0) ("*Determines whether two sequences are equal according to an equality comparer.*"), and even [the code](https://github.com/steveharter/dotnet_corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/SequenceEqual.cs#L14), I am still a bit confused why the index-by-index / combined .MoveNext and .Equals() calls can yield a true here overall.

If anyone can shed some light on why this is happening, I'd highly appreciate a bit more insight here.

Comment: `a` will contain only  "A" and "B".

Comment: I'm more interested in why you think that would *not* be the case. Like, what do you think should be happening here?

Comment: I agree with @Blindy, the interesting part here is *why* you thought these should be different, as this would probably tell us what the answer should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0), emphasis mine:

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains **no duplicate elements**, and whose elements are in **no particular order**.

And further:

> The `HashSet<T>` class is based on the model of mathematical sets and provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys of the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` or Hashtable collections.

Given those two remarks,

```
// a ends up containing "A" and "B", rather than "A", "A", and "B"
var a = new HashSet<string>(){  "A", "A", "B" };
var b = new HashSet<string>(){  "A", "B" };

var areTheyEqual = a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

and so they are equivalent. But as the documentation states, though, `HashSet`s implementation makes no guarantees about the order in which items are stored or iterated over. That means you shouldn't rely on the comparisons between two `HashSet`s working, even if you looked at the implementation for the current version of .NET, as the implementation is free to change the ordering for any future version.

Instead, you can use [SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=net-5.0):

> A `SortedSet<T>` object maintains a sorted order without affecting performance as elements are inserted and deleted. Duplicate elements are not allowed. Changing the sort values of existing items is not supported and may lead to unexpected behavior.

Thus, given:

```
var a = new SortedSet<string>() { "A", "A", "B" };
var b = new SortedSet<string>() { "B", "A" };

a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

These are considered equal.

---

As an aside, `HashSet`'s [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-5.0) method, and `SortedSet`'s [`equivalent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.add?view=net-5.0), returns `bool`, which is `true` if an item was added to the collection, and `false` if not. This gives you a way to determine when you're attempting to insert duplicates, if this is important to you at the time of insertion. This is in contrast to `List.Add()`, where a list will happily store duplicates, meaning the difference in API here helps to communicate the difference between the collection types.

Comment: @JörgBattermann I've edited my answer to include an explanation about ordering/comparisons that I missed out.

Comment: `HashSet` has a `SetEquals` function, so switching to `SortedSet` is not necessary if all you want is comparing sets. Of course there are many applications where a well defined iteration order is necessary or preferable, so `SortedSet` is often the right choice.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks very much. I've never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

@John H's answer does not tell the full story.

This test passes.

```
public void SequenceEqualTest()
{
    var a = new HashSet<string> { "A", "A", "B" };
    var b = new HashSet<string> { "A", "B"};
    var c = new HashSet<string> { "B", "A"};
    a.SequenceEqual(b).Should().BeTrue();
    a.SequenceEqual(c).Should().BeFalse();
    b.SequenceEqual(c).Should().BeFalse();
}
```

The first assertion makes sense because initializing with "A", "A", "B" is the same as "A", "B" because the second "A" is thrown out by calling a private method, `AddIfNotPresent`.

While

> whose elements are in no particular order

is true, in pragmatic terms, the order for both initializations will result in the same underlying data structure, which uses the same underlying deterministic enumerator. That enumerator over both hash sets thus gives you the same result for `SequenceEqual`.

So why are the next two assertions false?

Well, the constructors above take an `IEnumerable<string>`, which has the deterministic order specified by the calling code; `a` and `b` have one order, and `c` has the opposite order. This constructor calls [UnionWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.unionwith?view=net-5.0), which operates over the input collection calling  `AddIfNotPresent`, which uses a bucketing mechanism as you'd expect for hash tables. That mechanism results with the contents being in different buckets.

Here's what I mean. Under the debugger for `a` and `c` we get

| a | c |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

which clearly shows the internal slots in the data structure are flipped. The meat of the enumerator is

```
while (_index < _set._lastIndex)
{
    if (_set._slots[_index].hashCode >= 0)
    {
        _current = _set._slots[_index].value;
        _index++;
        return true;
    }
    _index++;
}
```

which clearly shows the code enumerates deterministically from the lowest indexed slot to the highest.